# c++ shared_ptr as type of operator[]

Tags: c++, class, unique, shared-ptr, virtual

I'm working with `operator[]`, which should return 3 different types {`Drink`, `Dish`, `Kit`}. So I was told that I should use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` with `<Product>` in brackets. `Product` is the parent class for these 3 classes.

Everything works, until I need to use methods of the objects. For example, I want to have method `print()` printing in a way that I made for `Drink`. Instead of that, it's printing the method of class `Product` (so it's obvious, but doesn't solve the problem with magic usage of `shared_ptr`).

Class `Product` has virtual method, so I don't think that the problem is there.

```
class Menu
{
    vector<Dish> dishes;
    vector<Drink> drinks;
    vector<Kit> kits;

public:
    Menu(){};

    shared_ptr<Product> operator[](pair<int,int> pairr)
    {
        if(pairr.first == 1)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Product> my_str_ptr;
            my_str_ptr = std::make_shared<Product>(drinks[pairr.second-1]);
            return my_str_ptr;
        }
        if(pairr.first == 2)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Product> my_str_ptr;
            my_str_ptr = std::make_shared<Product>(dishes[pairr.second-1]);
            return my_str_ptr;
        }
        if(pairr.first == 3)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Product> my_str_ptr;
            my_str_ptr = std::make_shared<Product>(drinks[pairr.second-1]);
            return my_str_ptr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you put some code to this example? It is hard to understand what you are referring too.

Comment: `std::make_shared<Product>` constructs an actual `Product` object, not a `Dish`, `Drink` or `Kit`. So your code is behaving correctly as written, it always returns a `shared_ptr<Product>` that points to an actual `Product`, not a subclass.

Comment: So is there any option that it will refer to Dish, Drink, or Kit calling operator[] because I cant't have 3 the same operators returning different data type

Comment: A `std::shared_ptr<Product>` can be constructed directly from a `std::shared_ptr<Drink>`.   So, for example, if `pairr.first == 1` all that is necessary is `return std::make_shared<Drink>(drinks[pairr.second-1]);`.    Same sort of logic for the other derived classes (where `Product` is an accessible base).    Additional note:  To avoid undefined behaviour, it would be advisable to handle cases where `pairr.second-1` is not a valid index of the relevant vector, and also handle cases where `pairr.first` is not `1`, `2`, or `3` (e.g. by throwing an exception or by returning a null `shared_ptr`).

Comment: This looks like a bad API design. It is had to tell how it should look like without description of context and requirements. Anyway `std::shared_ptr` is not needed it is possible to make it more like usually `operator[]` works, just by returning a reference.

Comment: Never make a shared_ptr of something you don't own. In this case the vectors own the objects sou you can't return them as shared_ptr. For `operator []` to return shared_ptr you need the vectors to hold `shared_ptr` already.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: `make_shared` creates a new object; that object IS owned by the shared pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt which breaks half the functionality of `operator []`. No more `x[i] = y;`. And if that is what you want then `unique_ptr` would be the right thing to use since the caller will be the only one owning the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the derived type you want to return, rather than making the base class.

Also, a `unique_ptr` is probably a better choice than `shared_ptr`, unless you have additional requirements that make the `shared_ptr` preferred.

In C++, it is conventional to use 0-based indexing (*cardinal offset*) rather than 1-based indexing (*ordinal index*).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::make_unique;
using std::pair;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::vector;

namespace {

struct Product {
    virtual ~Product() = default;
    Product() = default;
    Product(Product const&) = default;
    virtual auto Name() const -> string { return "Product"; }
};

struct Dish : Product {
    auto Name() const -> string override { return "Dish"; }
};

struct Drink : Product {
    auto Name() const -> string override { return "Drink"; }
};

struct Kit : Product {
    auto Name() const -> string override { return "Kit"; }
};

enum class Prod { dish, drink, kit };

class Menu {
    vector<Dish> dishes{ Dish{}, Dish{}, Dish{} };
    vector<Drink> drinks{ Drink{} };
    vector<Kit> kits{ Kit{}, Kit{}, Kit{}, Kit{}, Kit{} };
public:
    auto operator[](pair<Prod, size_t> fs) -> unique_ptr<Product> {
        auto s = fs.second;
        if(fs.first == Prod::drink) {
            return make_unique<Drink>(drinks.at(s));
        }

        if(fs.first == Prod::dish) {
            return make_unique<Dish>(dishes.at(s));
        }

        if(fs.first == Prod::kit) {
            return make_unique<Kit>(kits.at(s));
        }

        return {};
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    Menu menu;
    auto product = menu[{Prod::drink, 0}];
    cout << product->Name() << "\n";
    product = menu[{Prod::kit, 3}];
    cout << product->Name() << "\n";
}
```

The `operator[](pair<Prod, size_t>)` is rather awkward, in my opinion.

As an alternative, you could use the *invoke operator*, `operator()(Prod, size_t)` to eliminate having to pass a `pair`.